# is there a way to make water armor and condense the water?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, materials, armors

i want to make an armor made of liquid, for example like dew accumulate and attached to the person or just dip into water and the water attached/carried on (just example), but it also condense the liquid (make it dense enough), to make it not easily scattered/splash away and to buoyant/pushaway any object at least something like a mass of steel mace and the force of bullet penetration from passing through.

inspired by this image:https://www.luckygunner.com/lounge/revolver-ammo-commentary/

[image]

i dont know the thickness, but i guess at least the minimum is as thick as plate armor. (correct me if that is to much for a protection thickness of this kind)

while the maximum thickness or density or heavyness at least not make the person cant move at all

the outer layer of the armor must be the liquid so no full coverage material like water bed or water baloon thing.

and its fine if other small substance or material disolve into the liquid like salt to create something like dead sea effect for the liquid armor.

and the inside layer can be any material or mechanism to keep the water in place or the person can be covered by this material but not the water itself (i mean the material not fully covering the water, like water bed for example), so something like a vest/suit or armor that work as inside layer (not necessarily protective as secondary armor) while the outer layer is liquid, the liquid itself is not must be attached directly on the persons naked body either.

the liquid and the mechanism or material doesnt necessarily attached either it can have some gap or floating around it, like for example because it have magnetic field (i dont know is this can work in this case though, this just an example)

here a rough image to (maybe) help to imagine what i mean

[image]

balistic gel or something like jelly is out of the question, i want proper liquid.

is there a method or chemical that can achieve what i describe ?

i know theres many ways to counter this armor like boiling or freezing it or maybe using water repelant substance or even electrocution but thats not part of my question.

feel free to suggest better liquid material for the liquid armor if water is not possible or a bad material for liquid armor.

Comment: Where do I start from? Water vapor is not liquid, pressurized water is not condensed. I don't know where you got these idea from. Please make your question scientifically sound.

Comment: Not gonna post an answer, but consider that [you need nearly a metre of water](https://mythresults.com/episode34) to stop a supersonic bullet, and lower velocity bullets can travel through that much water and still, apparently, have lethal velocity. Your armour is going to be **Really Heavy**. You could use mercury, if you weren't adverse to chronic brain damage...

Comment: I see no way to answer this with the science based tag

Comment: no proper answer due to the tag is one thing,  but iam not sure this is to broad, at least tell me the reason what part of it is broad....

Answer (score 8):

> balistic gel or something like jelly is out of the question, i want proper liquid.

That leave all non-liquids out of the question.

In fact, you are leaving all newtonian liquids out of the question, because they would fill the container in which they are in... and therfore not remain stuck to the person/object.

Now out of the non-newtonians... I bet you do not want something like gelatine. That would not be "proper liquid", if I understand you correctly.

Out of what is left... perhaps you can cover the person in [Whipped cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipped_cream). Yeah, not great armor.

Ah, another idea came to me: you can try a [Ferrofluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrofluid), held by an array magnets below it... I bet the magnets would be the ones absorbing the impacts.

No, sorry, no. I think you need a [magic](/questions/tagged/magic) tag there.

Comment: Even without the "proper-liquid"-rule, I really doubt that you can find anything that works as an armor. Even if you used balistic gel, you would need it to be 20cm thick or so at least.

Comment: "Sir! we're outgunned and outmatched! what are your orders!?" "Bring out the whipped cream. I read on WBuilding stackexchange that it can be used as armour. We might die horribly, but at least we'll go out delicious!"

Answer (score 2):

**Hydrophilic fibers.**

Imagine a coat made of a very fluffy terry towel.  It will hold water because it is made of hydrophilic cotton fibers.  You might soak the coat and put it on to stay cool.  Now make the fibers as small as you can: terrycloth made of the finest spun silk.  Make them stiff so they do not droop under the weight of the water.  Make them tightly curled so they interlock and support each other, holding drops in their curly interstices.   This water armor coat is 100 times fluffier than your terrycloth soak coat and even more strongly hydrophilic.   It is in the shape of a sphere.  It will hold a lot of water, this coat.  It will be really heavy, too - the weight of a sphere of water.  Good thing you have been doing squats, and lots of them.

That is my proposition for your armor.  It is a super fluffy, soaking wet towel coat.  You could have it in bold primary colors too, which would be a sharp look.